# Need to combine two SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two code samples that I would like to combine.  The first provides the number of people in Jail for a point in time.

```
SELECT
    COUNT (Distinct b.BookingNumber)
FROM 
    Booking b
INNER JOIN 
    HousingNodePersonHistory hnph ON b.BookingKey = hnph.BookingKey
INNER JOIN 
    View_Housing vh ON hnph.HousingNodeKey = vh.HousingNodeKey
WHERE 
    b.BookingDateTime <= '2018-08-13 06:23:59.999'
    AND hnph.BeginDateTime <= '2018-08-13 06:23:59.999' 
    AND (hnph.EndDateTime >= '2018-08-13 06:23:59.999' OR hnph.EndDateTime IS NULL OR hnph.EndDateTime = '')
    AND (vh.HousingDescription LIKE '%ACJ%')
```

The second returns a list of datetimes that I would like the first to use to give me the same population return for every day in 2018 so I can provide an updated average daily population for 2018.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000',
        @EndDate   DATETIME = GETDATE();

WITH theDates AS
(
    SELECT 
        @StartDate AS theDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(DAY, 1, theDate)
    FROM 
        theDates
    WHERE 
        DATEADD(DAY, 1, theDate) <= @EndDate
)   
SELECT 
    theDate
    --,1 as theValue
FROM 
    theDates
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Is there any way to use the dates provided by the second query to populate and run in the where clause in the first query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `join`:

```
WITH theDates AS (
      SELECT @StartDate as theDate
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, theDate)
      FROM theDates
      WHERE DATEADD(day, 1, theDate) <= @EndDate
     ) 
SELECT d.theDate, COUNT(Distinct b.BookingNumber)
FROM (SELECT d.theDate, DATEADD(minute, d.theDate, 6*60 + 24) as ddhhmm
      FROM thedates d
     ) d CROSS JOIN
     Booking b JOIN
     HousingNodePersonHistory hnph
     ON b.BookingKey = hnph.BookingKey JOIN
     View_Housing vh
     ON hnph.HousingNodeKey = vh.HousingNodeKey
WHERE b.BookingDateTime <= d.ddhhmm AND
      hnph.BeginDateTime <= d.ddhhmm AND
      (hnph.EndDateTime >= d.ddhhmm OR hnph.EndDateTime IS NULL OR hnph.EndDateTime = ''
      ) AND
      vh.HousingDescription LIKE '%ACJ%' 
GROUP BY d.theDate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by adding a day range to your calendar table and filtering by day. You then simply add the StartDate in the select list and aggregate it in the `GROUP BY`.

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000'
       ,@EndDate   datetime = GETDATE()

     ;WITH theDates AS
     (SELECT @StartDate as startDate, DATEADD(minute,-1,DATEADD(day,1,@StartDate)) as endDate
      UNION ALL
      SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, startDate) as startDate, DATEADD(minute,-1,DATEADD(day,2,startDate))  as endDate
        FROM theDates
       WHERE DATEADD(day, 1, startDate) <= @EndDate
     )

    Select 
        StartDate = theDates.startDate,  
        BookingCount = COUNT (Distinct b.BookingNumber)
    FROM 
        Booking b
        INNER JOIN HousingNodePersonHistory hnph ON b.BookingKey = hnph.BookingKey
        INNER JOIN View_Housing vh ON hnph.HousingNodeKey = vh.HousingNodeKey
        INNER JOIN theDates D ON b.BookingDateTime BETWEEN D.startDate AND d.endDate 
    WHERE 
        vh.HousingDescription LIKE '%ACJ%'
    GROUP BY
       theDates.StartDate
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```